# Trouble with INSERT statement and Coldfusion

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion, insert

I asked a similar question but the details were too long for a comment there. I have an insert statement in CF that is inputting values into an empty table in a MYSQL database. When I input the values into the CF INSERT statement manually it works great. But when I try to let CF insert the data from the form nothing happens. There is no error message and the web page comes up just fine. My CF statement looks like this:

```
<cfquery name="updateInsOpTable" datasource="applewood">
INSERT INTO ins_opt_table (address,option1,option2,option3,-etc.)
VALUES ('#form.address#','#form.option1#','#form.option2#','#form.option3#'-etc.)
</cfquery>
```

This is my form:

```
<p>
<cfoutput query="getCategory">
<cfif #idOpCategories# IS 1>
#UCase(getCategory.categoryName)#

</cfif>
</cfoutput>

</p>

<p>

<cfoutput query="getOptions">
<cfif idOpCategories eq 1>
<input type="checkbox" value="#getOptions.idOptions#" name="option1" />
#getOptions.option# <br />
</cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the FORM scope before running the INSERT in order to verify the data is correct? Have you put a TRY/CATCH around the CFQUERY to catch any errors? What have you tried to do to debug this issue?

Comment: Yes, the dump turns out fine as well. I even put the word "Done" after the INSERT statement and it printed out fine. I have also placed data manually into the insert statement and that worked like it should. I'm not that proficient in CF so I'm not very familiar with TRY/CATCH. I will review the reference and try it. I do have a a CFIF statement right before the query: <cfif IsDefined(#form.submitOptions#)>

Comment: "the dump turns out fine"   What does this mean?  Does this mean it dumps the values you're expecting?  Add this parameter to the cfquery:  result = "resultdump"  and the do a cfdump for resultdump.  Does the query look like it's supposed to?

Comment: Part of the problem might be that unchecked checkboxes will not exist in the FORM scope if they're unchecked. You need `<cfparam name="form.option1" default="">` etc. You also, _really_, should be using `cfqueryparam` in your query rather than what you're doing.

Comment: The dump showed all the variables of the form. I have removed the if statement and that worked. I want the if statement in there though.

Comment: This is called debugging.  So now you know there's a problem with your if conditional, right?  What could you try in order to fix that?

Comment: I just took out the if statement. As I said it's been a while since I had to do CF so my skills are sorely lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CFIF statement was the problem. I had it formatted wrong, which shows my rusty skills. I was using:

```
IsDefined(#form.submitOptions#)
```

and the code that actually worked is:

```
IsDefined("form.submitOptions")
```

Comment: FYI, `IsDefined` expects the *name* of a variable. By using # signs around the variable you were actually passing in the *value* of that field as the "name". That is why it did not work. That said, `StructKeyExists` is generally preferred over `IsDefined` because it is more precise.

Comment: I usually use the most basic of CF commands. When I do work for clients I usually stick to what I know so I don't take too long learning commands I'm not familiar with. I know that I should take time to further my knowledge and I will be looking into the info everyone has given me here. I appreciate the education, and the edit.